# How to make raw_input accept multiple answers in a simple, fast manner

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a python project and I need it to be able to accept multiple answers. I've figured a way to do it, but it´s too lengthy. So, what I've got looks like this:

```
def part_one () :
    answer_one = raw_input ('>>> ').lower()
    try: 
        if answer_one == 'apple' or answer_one == 'orange' or answer_one == 'banana' :
            chapter_one()
```

It does what I want it to do (if the user writes any of those answers, s/he will advance). My problem is that I need there to be around 500 answers... So, is there any way to get my code to do the same without having to write `or answer_one == 'X'` over and over again?

Comment: `if answer_one == 'apple' or answer_one == 'orange' or answer_one == 'banana' :` try change this row to `if answer_one in ('apple', 'orange', 'banana'):`

Comment: Works aswell, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a set:

```
mylist = {'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'}
def part_one () :
    answer_one = raw_input ('>>> ').lower()
    if answer_one in mylist:
        chapter_one()
```

Comment: If the `mylist` is small enough, won't a tuple be faster than the dict?

Comment: Why you use `set` for list of fruits and  didn't use tuple?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Actually, this is a set and not a dictionary. A set is actually faster to use the `in` operator with (`O(1)` compared to `O(n)`, I believe). Think of it as an unordered list

Comment: @itdxer Read above^ :)

Comment: @Haidro How you can explain this code:
`>>> timeit.timeit('c = set(range(1,10000000)); print(9999999999 in c)', number=1)`
answer: False
time: 0.5635550022125244
`>>> timeit.timeit('c = tuple(range(1,10000000)); print(9999999999 in c)', number=1)`
answer: False
time: 0.33982110023498535`

Comment: @itdxer For starters, you're only doing it once. That time also includes creating the set/tuple

Comment: @Haidro But if you need create `set` from 500 elements you didn't do that by hands, you also generate it from code, and will not be so faster as you say before.

Comment: `>>> timeit.timeit('c = {1,2,3,4,5}; a = 9999999999 in c', number=10000000)`
time: 2.13989520072937
`>>> timeit.timeit('c = (1,2,3,4,5); a = 9999999999 in c', number=10000000)`
time: 0.8828270435333252

Comment: @Haidro as you see I didn't generate them and tuple still faster

Comment: @Haidro Maybe this is some new future from Python 3?

Comment: @itdxer I really have no idea what you're trying to prove here, but let me expand more. A set is different to a tuple. It has more advantages, such as quick lookup (which your timings definitely do not prove), and you can use functions with sets (useful ones). Once again you're creating your set/tuple while you're timing it. And sets aren't for minimal data; in that case sure, use a tuple/list. But as the OP is using 500+ items, a set would be much more efficient

Comment: @itdxer This is just my understandment, anyway. There's probably a more detailed description of sets and lists/tuples somewhere else, probably on SO

Comment: Just a quick note if other newby users like me come across this post: remember to keep all the items in the list in lowercase if you are using ".lower()" later.

Comment: It's only a words, without any proof, but test code say that `set` isn't faster check then `tuple`.